# Display dataframe in a separate panel in Jupyter Lab

Tags: dataframe, jupyter, jupyter-lab

I would like to display my dataframe in a seperate panel/window in Jupyter Lab. Currently, I can open .csv files in a separate window (which helps write code side-by-side to the data I'm working with), but I want to do this with active dataframes as well.

Is there a way to do this native to Jupyterlab, similar to how it is done in MATLAB? If not, what is the best way to do it otherwise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. There are several ways:

1. Display the data frame in a cell output, then right-click on the output and select `Create New View for Output`
   [image: Create New View for Output1]
2. Use [jupyterlab-sidecar](https://github.com/jupyter-widgets/jupyterlab-sidecar) package:

   ```py
   from sidecar import Sidecar

   sc = Sidecar(title='My dataframe')
   with sc:
       display(df)
   ```

   [image]
3. (JupyterLab 3.3+) Activate the visual debugger, go to variables list, hover over the variable and click on loop icon.
   [image: debugger]

You can combine approach (1) or (2) with IPython widgets to create an interactive explorer for larger data frames, such as this [`pandas_explorer`](https://gist.github.com/krassowski/159bb0c76ff47edb031710e2cff6862f) snippet. There are other, more complete, interactive explorers which you can embed in a sidecar or move to the new output, for example [ipydatagrid](https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid).

Comment: This is great, thanks. The third method (using the debugger) was mostly what I was looking for, in that it automatically updates the value as I work on the dataframe. Is there a way to have the third option provide a scrollable view instead of just the first 5 and last 5 rows? 

Edit: got it done by running this pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)

Comment: Agreed with @mswiz , exactly what I was looking for in terms of automatic updates to my dataframe! Now I just wish there was some way to pop-out the data viewer so I could place in my second monitor?