# Real time Pandas dataframe visualisation in Jupyter lab

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-lab, viewer

I'm looking for a tool that allows to visualize in real time the pandas dataframes with an excel look (filter and sort).

Does anyone know an extension of this type? Knowing of VS code proposes this tool, I am looking for the same thing on Jupyter Lab

When I say real time it means for example, when I modify a dataframe via a Pandas method (with inplace=True), it is reflected in the viewer.

Comment: What is the name of the tool in VSCode? That may provide a clue for searching.

Comment: It's provide by Jupyter extension from Microsoft

Comment: Maybe it is the 'Data Viewer' being referenced [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65883166/8508004)? If so, that looks most like #3 and that first comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964860/8508004), I referenced in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of anything that works quite like your describe; however, there's several that are close:

- There's [Perspective](https://github.com/finos/perspective) that features, "A JupyterLab widget and Python client library, for interactive data analysis in a notebook, as well as scalable production Voila and Holoviz applications". See [here](https://github.com/finos/perspective#features). It's built on [ipyregulartable](https://github.com/jpmorganchase/ipyregulartable).
- There's also [mitosheet](https://github.com/mito-ds/monorepo). "Mito is a spreadsheet that lives inside your JupyterLab notebooks. It allows you to edit Pandas dataframes like an Excel file, and generates Python code that corresponds to each of your edits." There's also [the JupyterLab Tabular Data Editor extension](https://github.com/jupytercalpoly/jupyterlab-tabular-data-editor).
- [HoloViz's Panel library DataFrame widget](https://panel.holoviz.org/reference/widgets/DataFrame.html). (I don't believe this one is limited to JupyterLab.) See under 'Display' where it says:

> "The DataFrame widget renders an table which allows directly editing the contents of the dataframe with any changes being synced with Python. Note that it modifies the pd.DataFrame in place."

- [JupyterLab Data Explorer](https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab-data-explorer)
- The last paragraph and the first comment [here in reply to 'Display dataframe in a separate panel in Jupyter Lab'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74964860/8508004) are particularly helpful pointing out some options.
- [ipysheet](https://github.com/QuantStack/ipysheet#ipysheet) now recommends [ipydatagrid](https://github.com/bloomberg/ipydatagrid#ipydatagrid)

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll take a look
I need to access a Dataframe while I'm working on a notebook, from a python script, locally.